# Non-planar Object tracking related questions

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, pose-estimation, object-tracking

I am currently working on a software to track real-world objects and place an equivalent 3D version on top of it.
For the past 6 months i have extensively researched and developed multiple versions of the software but i am now facing a problem i cannot solve nor find proper articles about it.

To summarize, the current state of the software is able to detect objects similar to what is done in this article
https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/d2c/tutorial_real_time_pose.html#gsc.tab=0

Which uses a combination of ORB pattern detection and SolvePnP to extract the object's pose from image frame key features.
But the problem is that it only works for planar objects, anything that is more complex, the software no longer can extract the correct pose and alignment.

I tried the article's method of getting the pose of the object, with the limitation of only working with planar objects.
I also tried going with an ICP (iterative closest point) approach but point-clouds are only generated with the camera movement and i need a way of tracking with a fixed camera and moving object.
I have started to look into POSIT but i don't know if it's a good option.

What am i missing in terms of implementations, how can i achieve complex geometry / non-planar pose tracking taking into consideration the article mentioned? And how would one keep the pose from one angle to another (360 view of an object)?
I would really appreciate some guidance in this matter!

The ultimate goal would be to recreate as close as possible this type of object tracking
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D60Q18lMTz8

Is solvepnp the correct path?

Cheers!

Comment: to get the object pose of a 3D object you need 3D reference points, then solvePnP will work.

Comment: As the article states and i as well use, the initial setup includes giving the 2d-3d pairs for when the ORB step takes action, after homography it gives back the best matches and defines the pose from it. The problem is that this only seems to be working for planar objects

Comment: 3x3 homography only works for planar surfaces. If you are able to find the (initial) 3D points of your keypoints on the 3D surface and then find good matches without using a 3x3 homography it should work. SolvePnP can handle 3D object's!

Comment: How would you suggest tackling the part of finding the 2d-3d pairs then? The homography supposedly is giving me the matches i need?!

Comment: that whole article doesn't mention homography even once. it does mention a planar model (single face of the box), but that's different from a homography -- I haven't worked through the article nor do I plan to. to me it looks like it just takes an initial view of one side of the box, collects the feature points on that, pins them to the model (that one face of it), and then uses that to recover the pose in future frames. there is nothing in principle preventing you from doing that to arbitrary faces of the model.

Comment: The article doesn't mention but the code has a secondary filtering method that uses homography. That being said, i would like to hear a way of finding matches without homography :) Also, how would one "stitch" multiple angles in order to maintain the correct pose? cheers

Comment: I have edited the initial question to include what i would like to achieve.

Comment: [crosspost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159): https://forum.opencv.org/t/non-planar-object-tracking/15835